# Get json response as verbose (no id references, always instances)

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have the following objects:

```
public class A
{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List <B> bs;
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class B
{
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

After the serialization, if I do a get with a restcontroller, I get something like this, first the complete instance and then the references:

```
    {
    "A": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "bs": [{
              "id": "1",
              "name": "b1"
            },
            {
              "id": "2",
              "name": "b2"
            }]
        },
    {
          "id": "2",
          "bs": ["1","2"]
        }]
    }
```

Is it any chance to get always the complete instance instead of the references?. E.g.

```
{
    "A": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "bs": [{
              "id": "1",
              "name": "b1"
            },
            {
              "id": "2",
              "name": "b2"
            }]
        },
{
          "id": "2",
          "bs": [{
              "id": "1",
              "name": "b1"
            },
            {
              "id": "2",
              "name": "b2"
            }]
        }]
    }
```

Comment: Is removing the `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation from your class not an option?

Comment: No, because before this, I serialize all from a json file with references too. And without that, I get an Exception from jackson

Comment: Then I think your best bet would be to use a mix-in for this specific case in which you override the `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation to use `ObjectIdGenerators.None`.

Comment: You probably want to replace one of the tags on your question with a `java` tag. You'll get a lot more views/answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you indicated in the comments that you rely on the `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation for deserialization, removing the annotation is not an option.

What you can do, however, is create a mix-in that specifically overrides the object identity behavior for this specific use case:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.None.class)
public abstract class BMixIn {}
```

And then register it on the `ObjectMapper` that you use to write the output:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.addMixIn(B.class, BMixIn.class);
```

Comment: I get the following error: Cannot construct instance of `B` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2')

Comment: You shouldn't use the `ObjectMapper` with the mix-in to deserialize, only to serialize.

Comment: I think that I explained something wrong, I deserialize a json file into a java object and then, that is the object which is send by the restcontroller. Should I update the question?

Comment: So you want to deserialize JSON that has the ID references, and then serialize it again with the full instance information?

Comment: Yes. That is my problem.

Comment: Just a matter of using two different object mappers. One with the mix-in and one without.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167716/discussion-between-iker-aguayo-and-robby-cornelissen).